# Unable to instantiate application error which extends Application class

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

The below error occurs sometimes for some users.
I haven't seen it through android phones which I have for testing, but I got this crush via Google developer console.

```
[Error]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.***.***.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.***.***.MyApplication
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4253)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.***.***.MyApplication
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
... 11 more

[MyApplication.java]
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
            ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

    ...

}

[manifest.xml]
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
...
<application
        android:name="com.***.***.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

I've tried to find out to solve this problem.
I doubt it might be due to external SD card problem or 'public constructor'.
Because even I do not know how to reenact the situation, I can't be sure whether this is due to SD card or public constructor stuff.

I'm sure there's somebody who got this error and already know how to solve this.
Thus, please help me know what's wrong and how I can fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: have you add the class name in manifest file in applciation tag.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your class name in your manifest file. hope this solve your problem

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyApplication">

  ........
```

for further reading , how to extends Application class, read [here](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/).

Comment: Thanks for answering the question :)
You mean that I should remove the package name at 'android:name' tag on Manifest.xml ?
(android:name="com.***.***.MyApplication -> android:name=".MyApplication")
If that is what I should do, then could you tell me why or let me know something like document or link ?

Comment: just replace that with your class name.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not follwing your meaning.
There already is the 'name' attribute on Application tag as 'com.***.***.MyApplication'.
What I understood from your comment is to replace it to just '.MyApplication'.
Can you explain What is different?
Thanks

Comment: i assumed you have not defined class name there.

Comment: I already put manifest.xml on the question part.
And there is 'name' attribute on Application tag.
So if there is no difference between 'com.***.***.MyApplication' and '.MyApplication', then I guess there might be another cuase..

Comment: does your package name contain *?

Comment: The reason why I used '**' is because I did not want to show the full package name of the app.
Actual package name doesn't contain '**'.

Comment: can you please post your full manifest file and your first activity .